# Why am I getting a "bash: cat - : command not found" error in my bash script?

Tags: shell, unix

I'm writing a shell script that runs another program every so often.

This is my current attempt:

```
           inputFile=$1
percentageBufferFill=$2
        outputTarget=$3
          outputFile=$4

mbuffer -i $inputFile -P $percentageBufferFill | ssh $outputTarget \"cat - > $outputFile \"
```

I'm getting an error message but I'm not sure what it means:

```
summary:  0.0 KiByte in  0.0sec - average of  0.0 KiB/s
bash: cat - : command not found
```

What is this error message telling me about my script?

Comment: Don't escape the double quotes.

Comment: Thanks. That actually fixed it (Sorry about the comment earlier saying it didn't. Have this script on several computers and was running the wrong copy. Linux is hard.)

Comment: Don't edit your question to fix the error. That leaves the question invalid. Either delete the question if you don't think it is worth anything anymore or add the fix as an answer (ideally with some explanation).

Comment: Right. I've restored the question to its original form. My bad.